# Rails 5.2: Variables not accessible in header partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables, partials

Beginner here. Please be patient.

I'm attempting to port a PHP site to Rails and so far doing quite well, but can't figure out this one...

```
# [controllers/pages_controller.rb]
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate, except: [:show]
  before_action :set_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /pages
  # GET /pages.json
  def index
    @pages = Page.all
  end

  # GET /pages/1
  # GET /pages/1.json
  def show
    # This works:
    @page_title = @page.title

    # Do I really need to do this for each var?
    @page_description = @page.description
  end

  # GET /pages/new
  def new
    @page = Page.new
  end

  # GET /pages/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /pages
  # POST /pages.json
  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.save
        format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page added.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @page }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /pages/1
  # PATCH/PUT /pages/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.update(page_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @page }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pages/1
  # DELETE /pages/1.json
  def destroy
    @page.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pages_url, notice: 'Page deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_page
      @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def page_params
      params.require(:page).permit(:title, :type, :flag, :caption, :description, :share_image, :complete, :state, :offline_message, :active_from, :active_until, :mailing_list, :feed_url, :visible)
    end
end
```

If I write `<%= @page.description %>` into the partial directly, I get an error.
If I write `<%= @page_description %>` instead (with underscore), no error.
The error reads:

```
NoMethodError at /login
undefined method `description' for nil:NilClass
```

I want to use it like this in my site header:

```
[views/layouts/application.rb]
...
<meta name="keywords" content="<%= @page.keywords %>">
...
```

The information in this variable and many others is stored in the pages table because every page has different owners, facebook feeds, description, keywords, copyright date, and so on.
I want all that info to show up in the meta tags for each page.

So as far as I understand it, I go to pages/1 in the browser and the controller action `show` is accessed, which works even with no code inside; The variables from the table row with id 1 are all showing on the page itself but not in the header or footer partials.

Comment: Where is @page defined in controller action?

Comment: please add code in `pages_controller.rb`

Comment: I'm actually not sure because I get @page.title without adding any code at all to `def show` block. I assumed it was one of those magic vars that somehow appears in rails when you have a model. Does it need to be explicitly defined in the `def show` block?
My other pages also show the correct page title without my ever defining this variable.

Comment: Updated: Added pages_controller.rb in full.

Comment: Your `@page` variable is defined in `set_page` method, it is called before [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] actions (look at line #3 in the controller).

Comment: You have an error `at /login` url, why are you talking about pages#show? Could you please edit the question and add full server log with the error

Comment: Thank you. It was between chair and keyboard... all working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to use `@page_description`.

The error indicates that you don't have a @page object instantiated. Make sure that you have one. You can inspect the the @page object in the view like this:

```
<%= @page.inspect %>
```

If it says `nil`, then you need to set up this instance variable in your controller. For example:

```
@page = Page.find(params[:id])
```

Edit:

In this case it seems like you have a partial that is used in every layout that references the @page object. Now in the login page, the sessions / users controller does not provide this object.

Either you only use this partial in pages which are created by the page controller or you wrap your code with something like this:

```
<% if @page.present? %>
  <%= @page.description %>
<% end %>
```

To find out what controller you are in, in the partial, you can add this line:

```
<%= controller.class %>
```

Comment: I think this is already setup by virtue of the second before_action:

`before_action :set_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

In any case, adding it again hasn't changed anything.

Could it be about the application.rb data being called before it's been defined?

Comment: The line `NoMethodError at /login` indicates that this is not the PagesController but the UsersController or something similar. Are you using devise?

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize it had redirected to /login because of the before_action on line 2 and I was still making changes to pages_controller. Apparently, it was caused by a typo on one of my menu includes. Thank you for your answers. #ThatWasEmbarrassing